# Error message: Unused Variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I'm currently learning python and I recently created a script that contains two functions, one that creates an account for the user and another that logs the user into their current account.

[image]

However, after the user either logs in or enters an incorrect username/password I use a variable called Li that stands for Logged in. When the user is logged in the Li is set to True but when the user is not it is set to False. Thanks to VS code's helpful 'problems' ui  I learned that my script has an error. The error says that Li is an 'unused variable'. I don't understand this message and I was hoping someone else would. Thanks!

Comment: Please copy&paste the code as text into your question instead of linking to a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

VS code here just reminds you that you have declared a variable **Li** but didn't use anywhere further. You are assigning your **Li** variable True or False value, but what is the practical need for that? Because you currently don't associate any further logic with Li variable, you can simply omit it for now:

```
if accounts[user2] == pass2:
    return "You are now logged in"
else:
    return "Try again, your username and password was incorrect"
```

However, if you will add a real use-case for your variable further, warning from VS code will disappear as well, for example:

```
if accounts[user2] == pass2:
    Li = True
    return "You are now logged in"
else:
    Li = False
    return "Try again, your username and password was incorrect"

if Li:
    doSomeStuff()
```